# How to assign multiple external IP to a google cloud instances using terraform

Tags: google-compute-engine, terraform

I am able to add an external IP to the instance by the following code.

```
network_interface {
subnetwork = "${europe-staging-subnetwork.self_link}"


access_config {
  nat_ip = "${google_compute_address.external_ip.address}"
}
}

resource "google_compute_network" "staging-network" {
name                    = "staging-network"
auto_create_subnetworks = "false"
}
resource "google_compute_subnetwork" "europe-staging-subnetwork" {
name          = "europe-staging-subnetwork"
region        = "europe-west1"
ip_cidr_range = "#.#.#.#/16"
network       = "${google_compute_network.staging-network.self_link}"
}
```

But How will I assign multiple external IP to an instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [multiple network interfaces](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#top_of_page) to have multiple external IPs. The network interfaces need to be configured while [creating the instance](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#creating_virtual_machine_instances_with_multiple_network_interfaces) and these [cannot be modified or deleted](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces#limitations) after the instance has been created.